# Javascript filter search not working on backspace

Tags: javascript, search, filter

I'm having difficulties with building a simple filter search that goes through an array, It works but stops when I press backspace and It's not responsive

In my html I have

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Name" (keyup)='filterNames($event)'>
```

And in .js

```
filterNames(event) { 

    let input = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    this.temp = this.nameslist.filter(function (n) {
        return n.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;

    });
    this.nameslist = this.temp;


}
```

nameslist is my array with some values, temp I've declared as temp = [];

I don't see where's the issue and why my list doesn't react on backspace?

Comment: log `this.namelist` inside the function and check for the values.

Comment: filterNames function fires on key up.

Comment: could you please attach how you display filtered names?

Answer (score 3):

When you assign `this.nameslist = this.temp;` in the last line of code, `this.nameslist` contains only filtered values. And when you press backspace filtered values are not returning back, obviously. What you need to do is to use different variable to hold filtered list. `this.temp` - is fine. (but probably better to rename it to `this.filteredNamesList`). Consider this example:

```js
this.nameslist = [
  {firstName: 'Alex'},
  {firstName: 'Mike'},
  {firstName: 'Sridhar'}
];

this.temp = this.nameslist.slice(0, this.nameslist.lenght); //make a copy of names

function filterNames(elem) { 

    let input = elem.value.toLowerCase();
    this.temp = this.nameslist.filter(function (n) {
        return n.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;

    });
    console.log(this.temp);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Name" onKeyUp="filterNames(this)">
```

So, in this example `this.nameslist` always contain full list of your names, and `this.temp` contain a filtered list, and successfully handle backspace action.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like below

```js
filterNames(event) { 

    let input = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    this.nameslist = this.nameslist.filter(function (n) {
        return n.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;

    });


}
```